# "CiviCRM Upcoming" block displaying old events

Tags: blocks, civicrm

Currently running Drupal 7.61 with CiviCRM 5.7.2.

We have the "CiviCRM Upcoming" block enabled in our sidebar, however it continues to display events after their start date.

I've been fixing this by manually going into CiviCRM and disabling events which have passed, but ideally would like the Upcoming Events block to only display events which are actually upcoming (as I read it should here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC46/Event+Listings)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: would suggest you ask this on http://civicrm.stackexchange.com - also suggest you paste your view so someone can see what is going on

Comment: @petednz-fuzion thanks for the suggestion, i'll paste it onto the civicrm stackexchange! wasn't sure whether it would be best to ask here or there. in terms of pasting my view - sorry if this sounds daft but do you mean a screenshot of the settings or the website?

Comment: ah - i meant do a Views export - so someone can paste in to their site and build the same view to test

Comment: Just Views export isn't enough to rebuild it, you'd need related content types and fields too. Export can help but a views screenshot is also very helpful, and screenshots of related views settings. Just remember to come back and post your answer once you figure it out ;)